# how can I identify variable target on dataset for prediction with machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I'm working on a project to use the decision tree to predict attacks from log.

the problem is after normalizing the log files I don't know how to identify the output class in order to compare the results obtained from the decision tree with the real results.

to tell the truth I don't know how to identify the real class.

do i need to correlate in order to identify the class?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have target values as attacks in your dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is not clear. It would be great if your can share the logs or the result dataset that you are aiming for.

However, you can check if you are following Classification or Regression. The main difference between them is that the output variable in regression is numerical (or continuous) while that for classification is categorical (or discrete).

So check for the columns that fully describe the above(Classification or regression)

Comment: thank's @Running Rabbit, as i said before i normalize a set of log (snort log, access log from apache, error log from apache) with IDMEF protocol like this

enter image description here

and here is the original log file snort for exemple: bastion snort: [1:2001669:1] BLEEDING-EDGE Web Proxy GET Request [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2]: {TCP} 220.170.88.36:3047 -> 11.11.79.82:80

the aim is how do I get the class attack to identify if is an attack or not {yes, no} I don't know how can I found a real target class before using DTA for prediction.

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

thank's @Running Rabbit, as i said before i normalize a set of log (snort log, access log from apache, error log from apache) with IDMEF protocol like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eydJ4.png)

and here is the original log file snort for exemple:
bastion snort: [1:2001669:1] BLEEDING-EDGE Web Proxy GET Request [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2]: {TCP} 220.170.88.36:3047 -> 11.11.79.82:80

the aim is how do I get the class attack to identify if is an attack or not {yes, no} I don't know how can I found a real target class before using DTA for prediction.

Thank's